# Asked to review when queue is already cleared

Tags: bug

A couple of times I've had a brown background number indicating something to review.  I click on it, see an edit, note that it is reasonable and approve it.

I then get a page refresh saying there's nothing to review, but the indicator in the top bar still says there is.

Comment: There's nothing for *you* to review (because you have already reviewed all the items in the queue), but there are still items in the queue. The indicator is global - not just for you, hence what you see.

Comment: I have it 24/7 permanently. It happened when I cleared one of the rep hurdles, I forget which, and has remained ever since. I think you have to suck it up in this case.